# $\zeta$ is a $R^n$ bundle over paracompact space $B$. Then induced $\zeta\to\gamma^n(R^\infty)$ are all homotopic

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

This is related to Milnor, Characteristic Classes, Sec 5, Thm 5.7's implications.

Suppose $B$ is compact manifold. Let $V$ be a rank $k$ vector bundle over $B$. Let $\gamma_k$ be the $k-$plane bundle over $Gr_k(R^\infty)$ and $\gamma'_k$ be the vector $k-$plane bundle over $Gr_k(R^n)$ with $n$ large enough to allow a map $V\to\gamma'_k$.

From Thm 5.7, I deduce $V$ determines a unique map in $[B,Gr_k(R^\infty)]$. Since $B$ is compact, I deduce this map will factor through $Gr_k(R^n)$. Hence, this will determine a unique map $[B,Gr_k(R^n)]$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Since $Gr_k(R^\infty)=\lim_i Gr_k(R^i)$ where $\lim$ takes over directed system, do I have $[B,Gr_k(R^\infty)]=\lim_i[B,Gr_k(R^i)]$? So should direct limit commute with homotopy Hom? I doubt this is true. In other words, I want to conclude this unique family of maps determines an element of $[B,Gr_k(R^\infty)]$ by building it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone can probably tell you a more general statement, but here is a proof of the following: if $X$ is a compact space (I believe no CW structure is needed) and $Y$ is a CW complex with a skeletal filtration $Y_i$ ($i \geq 0$) with the property that $n$-skeleton is eventually contained in some $Y_k$, then $[X, Y]=\operatorname{colim}[X,Y_i]$.

There is an obvious map from the righthand side to the lefthand side given by including a representative into the whole of $Y$. It is easy to check this is well defined. It is injective since two maps into $Y_i$ that become homotopic in $Y$ are homotopic in some finite skeleton (via compactness) which means they are homotopic in some space of the filtration.

It is surjective since any map into $Y$ from $X$ is contained in a finite skeleton which by our assumption is contained in one of the $Y_i$.

Your knowledge from Milnor should allow you to check this fact applies.